# 2 different captions for tables and figures

Tags: formatting, captions

I want 2 different types of captions. One for table and another to figures.

I use this code for tables:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,nooneline]{caption}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{3pt}
```

and this for figures:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
```

the difference between things is in `nooneline`.

It is possible?

Answer (score 7):

If you pass options at package load, these options are set for all type of supported captions. However, if you use `\captionsetup[<type>]{<options>}` you can localize the settings to floats of type `<type>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=it}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{A table caption}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \caption{A figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Use the appropriate settings you require for each setup in this, individual way.

Comment: dont works. \usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,nooneline}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=bf}

Comment: @user46548: `nooneline` is deprecated (see the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf); section **C.1 caption v1.x**: "This version [v.3] of the `caption` package still supports the old options and commands provided by the version 1.0 to 1.4 of this package. So there shouldn’t occur any problems compiling old documents,
but please don’t mix old options and commands with the new ones. This isn’t supported and can cause ugly side effects.") Try with `singlelinecheck=off` instead of `nooneline`.